# Outputting Array Keys of Multi-Dimensional Array

Tags: php, arrays, key

I'm trying to write a function that takes a multi-dimensional array as input and outputs a multi-line string of keys like the following

```
['key']['subkey']
['key']['another_subkey']
['key']['another_subkey']['subkey_under_subkey']
['key']['yet_another_subkey']
['another_key']['etc']
```

Here is my attempt. It has problems when you get to the second level.

```
function get_array_keys_as_string($array){
    $output = "";
    foreach($array as $k => $v){
        if(is_array($v)){
            $string = get_array_keys_as_string($v);
            $prepend = "['$k']";
            $string = $prepend.str_replace("\n","\n".$prepend, $string);
            $output .= $string;
        }
        else{
            $output .= "['$k']\n";
        }
    }
    return $output;
}
```

I know I need a recursive function, but so far my attempts have come up short.

Comment: Can you provide  us with the  desired output ?

Comment: The above is the desired output as a string.

Comment: I know it would output the values also, but if you just need to inspect an array to see the structure why not just `print_r` it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the exact output you asked for use the following:

```
$arr = array(
    "key" => array(
        "subkey" => 1,
        "another_subkey" => array(
            "subkey_under_subkey" => 1
        ),
        "yet_another_subkey" => 1
    ),
    "another_key" => array(
        "etc" => 1
    )
);

function print_keys_recursive($array, $path = false) {
    foreach($array as $key=>$value) {       
        if(!is_array($value)) {
            echo $path."[".$key."]<br/>";
        } else {
            if($path) {
                echo $path."[".$key."]<br/>";
            }
            print_keys_recursive($value, $path."[".$key."]");
        }
    }
    return;
}
print_keys_recursive($arr);
```

Output:

```
[key][subkey]
[key][another_subkey]
[key][another_subkey][subkey_under_subkey]
[key][yet_another_subkey]
[another_key][etc]
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you want the output since you have not provided an example array, just the result, but here is an example based on the following array,

```
$array = array(
    "key" => array(
        "subkey" => 1, 
        "another_subkey" => array("2", "subkey_under_subkey" => 3), 
        "yet_another_subkey" => 4
    ),
    "another_key" => array("etc"), 
    "last_key" => 0
);
```

Using the following function,

```
function recursive_keys($arr, $history = NULL)
{
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value)
    {
        if (is_array($value))
            recursive_keys($value, $history."['".$key."']");
        else
            echo $history."['".$key."']\n";
    }
}
```

Output of `recursive_keys($array)` is,

```
['key']['subkey']
['key']['another_subkey']['0']
['key']['another_subkey']['subkey_under_subkey']
['key']['yet_another_subkey']
['another_key']['0']
['last_key']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function arrayMultiKeys($array,$depth = 0){
    foreach($array as $k=>$v){
        echo "['".$k."']";
        if(is_array($v)){
            arrayMultiKeys($v,$depth + 1);
        }
        if($depth == 0 ){
            echo "<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This function has a problem at the second level similar to mine, although it seems a lot cleaner in approach. A second second level key under the same first level key gets outputed as a third level key